Rigging character with eye
I have character in Blender when I parent it with the rigging and parent it with automatic weight. In the first, the eye was not moving with head bones, then I selected the eye and bones to make a parent with bones.
the problem is solved, but I have new problem.

and this is after I parent the eye with bone.


hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

What I think might be the problem is that you did not add weight to the eyes. I will suggest you do the following:

Select the eyes, select the bone to control the eyes CTRL + P > With Empty Groups



Select the eye balls and go to Edit Mode, Under the Properites panel, go to data tab

select the bone to move the object
Click the assign button below




I hope that will resolve the issue
